# Can I get ...args variables? I want to make MyLog(String format, Object... args)

Tags: java, logging, arguments

If I call

```
String name = "Chang";
int id = 1;
boolean isChecked = false;

MyLog.d(__FORMAT__, name, id, isChecked);
```

> MyLog.java

```
public static d(String foramt, Object... args) {
    Log.d(___TAG___, String.format(format, args));
}
```

I can get arg values. "Chang", 1, false.

But I do not know arg variables(?), "name", "id", "isChecked".

I want to log

```
name: Chang 
id: 1
isChecked:false
```

Can I get "name", "id", "isChecked" ?

Sorry poor Enlgish...

Comment: Are you looking for the args similar to the main method? Could you perhaps make a generic arraylist to be passed into the method? Or an object array? PS: In my opinion, your English is fine, no need to say sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In java, varargs parameters can be referenced like an array. For example, you can write:

```
System.out.println(args[0]);
```

If you're asking how you can get the names of the variables passed in, that's impossible. It would be better to make a class call Person, and then redeclare the method like this:

```
public static d(String foramt, Person... args) {
     for(Person p:args){
         //get the values of each object here and log them
     }
}
```

Comment: Oh Thank you~! What I want is Impossible... I did develop iOs (Obj-C). In Obj-C, that is possible. Now I develop Android, so I think that is possible, too...